# Witcher 3 Reason of State side quest

Tags: the-witcher-3

I never got this sidequest and I'm worried that it might effect the outcome of the game it says on this site I need to complete 4 side quest and I did all other 3 quests. Does it matter that I didn't do Reason of State. Can I still get the ciri lives and becomes a witcher outcome? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find info about all the endings on this page :
[Witcher 3 Endings](http://www.vg247.com/2015/05/28/the-witcher-3-how-to-get-the-best-ending/)

To get the witcher ending, Reason of State isn't necessary. Il it only required for the Empress ending.